# How do I edit the what goes on the edit view on my Sharepoint List?

Tags: sharepoint-list

[image]

How do I edit the what goes on the edit view on my Sharepoint List? 
I want to add/delete/rearrange items on my edit screen, however, when I press customize it goes into PowerApps.

Comment: Are you wanting to see different columns when you edit a list item compared to when you create a list item?

Answer (score 0):

Use the powerapps "Customize" option at the top right corner or in the "CommandBar-mainArea" and customize.

[image]

Comment: but if I customize it, it's not the same format and notes are displayed in a html format